# Reserving sub vectors while constructing

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have this:

```
size_t n = 100;
std::vector<std::vector<foo>> v(n);
```

The count of the `sub vectors` is dynamic but known. However, the number of items in each `vector` is not known but I have an estimation about it so I want to `reserve` the `sub vectors` before start pushing back into them. What I am currently doing is:

```
size_t estimated_size = 1000;
for (auto& sub_vector: v){
   sub_vector.reserve(estimated_size);
}
```

Is there a better way? Like doing it while constructing?

P.S. This is not an option:

```
size_t n = 100;
size_t estimated_size = 1000;
std::vector<std::vector<foo>> v(n, std::vector<foo>(estimated_size));
```

I just want to reserve without constructing because `foo` is costy to be constructed twice.

Comment: I think it depends much about how you're going to populate the inner vectors.

Comment: @LogicStuff May you please clarify a bit ?

Comment: "I just want to reserve without constructing because foo is costy to be constructed twice." - Don't store `foo`s directly? Maybe [`std::unique_ptr<foo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), or [`std::experimental::optional<foo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).

Comment: There is no way to reserve / pre-size `vector` at construction without constructing that number of objects. Unfortunately.

Comment: @BoBTFish: yes that could be an option... I may go for it if there is no other

Comment: @HumamHelfawi To be honest, I would go for the loop/`reserve()`. It's not all that bad really.

Comment: @Humam Are you going to be only `push_back`ing from different places of your code? I guess there's nothing to be done then... except maybe `shrink_to_fit` afterwards if the `estimated_size` is in some cases much bigger than it needs to be. Worth measuring.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Sorry, my comment was not precisely worded. Edited it. (I meant pre-sizing *at construction*.

Comment: @LogicStuff yup that is the case..

Comment: It's an interesting question, but what exactly do you mean when you say "better"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl not doing it with O(n) complexity. Cleaner to read is a bonus also

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: Perhaps you can reverse the logic: Construct each of the sub-vectors first, resizing them to your estimate, populating them, and only *then* creating the outer vector, initializing it with the sub-vectors. I doubt it will save that many clock cycles, though.

Comment: @DevSolar: "Construct each of the sub-vectors" where?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: I meant in your "real" code. Which I don't know, which is why I cannot make suggestions as to how that would work. In the end, I don't think this is something you should spend too much time agonizing over. Do whatever you think is most readable and best maintainable, and only return to the construct if it really turns out to be a bottleneck. (Which I doubt it will be.) I agree with BoBTFish, that loop doesn't look half bad.

Comment: @DevSolar I see.. many thanks :)

Comment: I just tested making a wrapping class to do the pre-reservation before returning an implicit conversion but, it seems, copying/coverting the object forgets any preallocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to do it while constructing the `vector` you could use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes two iterators and provide your own custom iterator. Dereferencing the iterator would create a vector reserve it and then return it:

```
class VectorReserveItr : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, foo> {
  size_t i;
  size_t capacity;
public:
  VectorReserveItr(size_t i, size_t capacity) : i(i), capacity(capacity) {}
  VectorReserveItr& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
  bool operator!=(const VectorReserveItr& rhs) { return i != rhs.i; }
  std::vector<foo> operator*() {
      std::vector<foo> ret;
      ret.reserve(capacity);
      return ret;
  }
};

std::vector<std::vector<foo>> v(VectorReserveItr(0, 1000), VectorReserveItr(100, 1000));
```

But I wouldn't expect it to be faster than a loop and I don't think it is more readable either.

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/OZ8OWf)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick countdown iterator:

```
template<class F,
  class T=std::result_of_t<F const&(std::size_t const&)>
>
struct countdown_iterator:
  std::iterator<
    std::input_iterator_tag,
    T,
    std::ptrdiff_t,
    T*,
    T
  >
{
  using self=countdown_iterator;
  std::size_t count_down = 0;
  F f;
  T operator*() const {
    return f(count_down);
  }
  self& operator++() {
    --count_down;
    return *this;
  }
  self operator++(int) {
    auto result = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return result;
  }
  friend bool operator==(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
    return lhs.count_down == rhs.count_down;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
};
```

a half-assed range class:

```
template<class It>
struct range {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  decltype(auto) front() const { return *begin(); }
  range():b(),e() {}
  range(It s, It f):b(s), e(f) {}
  range(range const&)=default;
  range& operator=(range const&)=default;
  ~range() = default;

  template<class C,
    class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<C>, range>>
  >
  range( C&& c ):
    range(std::begin(std::forward<C>(c)), std::end(std::forward<C>(c)))
  {}
};
template<class It>
range<It> make_range( It b, It e ) { return {std::move(b),std::move(e)}; };
```

and then we can count:

```
template<class F,
  class dF=std::decay_t<F>,
  class It=countdown_iterator<dF>
  class R=range<It>
>
R countdown( std::size_t N, F&& f ) {
  countdown_iterator e( N, f ):
  countdown_iterator b( N, std::forward<F>(f) );
  return {std::move(b),std::move(e)};
}
```

use:

```
size_t n = 100;

size_t m = 1000;
auto src = countdown(
  n,
  [m](auto&&){ std::vector<foo> v; v.reserve(m); return v; }
);
std::vector<std::vector<foo>> v;
v.reserve(100);
v.insert(v.end(), src.begin(), src.end() );
```

here we create a countdown "input" iterator that runs for 100 iterators.  Each time you dereference it it returns a vector with `m` capacity.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::vector<foo>> v(src.begin(), src.end());`?

Comment: @barry cannot write a random access input iterator (without backing store) due to reference problem.  So cannot expect vector to pre-size properly.  So havento manually reserve.  Simpky defining `-` might make it work on some compilers, similarly claiming to be random access despite having a value reference type, but I am being cautious.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-packing off of [Yakk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736840/2069064) answer here in a way that doesn't really involve writing my own code. With [Ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), we can do this directly by just building a range of `vector`s of the correct capacity. I also find this pretty easy to read:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = 
    view::ints(0, 100)
    | view::transform([](int ) {
        std::vector<int> sub_v;
        sub_v.reserve(100);
        return sub_v;
    });
```